# Sharing settings are not working as expected

Tags: sharing, permission-sets, sharing-rule, org-wide-defaults

OWD is set to **Private** and Grant Role Hierarchy is enabled. Sharing Settings is created for a custom object to give **Read Only** permission for that object to a Group based on some conditions.

But whenever I create a record or If I try to recalculate the Sharing rules, Based on those conditions Groups is not granted Read Only permissions.

Only if I keep OWD as Public Read Only those Sharing Rules are calculated, But that is not required as OWD is set to Public Read Only.

Comment: Record is created by community users... i.e record owners are community users

Comment: What are the details of the sharing rule you've implemented?